# Does Spring-graphl provide percentile metrics in spring-boot3?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-graphql

When using spring-graphl with spring-boot 2, I can set the following properties:
`management.graphql.autotime.percentiles-histogram: true` and I can get percentile histogram data metrics in prometheus with metrics named: `graphql_datafetcher_seconds_bucket`.

With the release of spring-boot 3, I see that spring-graph added observability support using Micrometers Observability api, and with that I no longer see any percentile histogram metrics. The configuration property mentioned above is  Is there a configuration I'm missing somewhere or is it no longer supported in spring-graphql?

Comment: I can’t seem to find where this « management.graphql.autotime.percentiles-histogram » property comes from. Can you point a reference to this?

Comment: When this property is set, it calls publishPercentileHistogram() on the timer builder in AutoTimeProperties.java if this property is set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, autotime support has been removed in Spring Boot 3.0 for Spring for GraphQL because `@Timed` is not supported for this instrumentation.

You can replace this with [a per-metric configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.metrics.customizing.per-meter-properties):

```
management.metrics.distribution.graphql.percentiles-histogram=true
```